# IEEEeqnarray reference subequations and subequation set

Tags: equations

I've a pair of equations and I want to reference to them once using the sub-eqations, i.e. (1a),(1b) and once reffering to both of by using (1). How to do that?

Here is what I've so far:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,IEEEtrantools}

\begin{document}
\begin{IEEEeqnarray}{CC}
\IEEEyesnumber \IEEEyessubnumber*
bla bla & blub blub \label{eq:sub1}\\
bla bla & bla bla  \label{eq:sub2}
\end{IEEEeqnarray}

asd \eqref{eq:sub1}, \eqref{eq:sub2}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

As the manual for IEEEtran explains, just add the label after `\IEEEyesnumber`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,IEEEtrantools}

\begin{document}
\begin{IEEEeqnarray}{CC}
\IEEEyesnumber\label{eq:both} \IEEEyessubnumber*
bla bla & blub blub \label{eq:sub1}\\
bla bla & bla bla  \label{eq:sub2}
\end{IEEEeqnarray}
where the set of equations \eqref{eq:sub1} and \eqref{eq:sub2}
is referred to as \eqref{eq:both}.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

My own first solution, please tell me weather this is good.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,IEEEtrantools}
\begin{document}
\begin{subequations}
\label{eq:main}
\begin{IEEEeqnarray}{CC}
\IEEEyesnumber
bla bla & blub blub \label{eq:sub1}\\
bla bla & bla bla  \label{eq:sub2}
\end{IEEEeqnarray}
\end{subequations}
asd \eqref{eq:sub1}, \eqref{eq:sub2} and \eqref{eq:main}
\end{document}
```